# Equation in Beamer starts enumeration from 0.1 instead of 1?

Tags: beamer, equations

I'm not sure how to fix this, I tried to find some old resources but googling mostly yielded tips for other document classes and often changing from chapters to articles or such. Here is the preamble and the equation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,amsthm}

\usefonttheme{serif}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usecolortheme{lily}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue!20,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg = blue!10, fg = black}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg = cyan}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg = cyan}

\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=cyan}

\def\B{{\mathcal B}}
\def\K{{\mathcal K}}
\def\H{{\mathcal H}}
\def\I{{\mathcal I}}
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}
\def\T{{\mathbb T}}
\def\NN{{\mathcal N}}
\def\C{{\mathbb C}}
\def\R{{\mathbb R}}
\def\Z{{\mathbb Z}}
\def\D{{\mathbb D}}
\def\M{{\mathcal M}}
\def\L{{\mathcal L}}
\def\E{{\mathcal E}}
\def\CC{{\mathfrak C}}
\def\CI{C^\infty(a,b)}
\def\la{\lambda}
% \def\L{\Lambda}
\def\bl{\overline{\lambda}}
\def\bz{\overline{\zeta}}
\def\v{\varphi}
\def\p{\psi}
\def\u{{\bf u}}
\def\j{{\bf j}}
\def\i{{\bf i}}
\def\x{{\bf x}}
\def\y{{\bf y}}
\def\f{{\bf f}}
\def\g{{\bf g}}
\def\o{\omega}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\al{\alpha}
\def\ld{,\ldots,}
\def\z{\zeta}
\def\te{\theta}
%\def\g{\gamma}
\def\fv{\frac{f}{\varphi}}
\def\fvi{\frac{f_i}{\varphi_i}}
\newcommand{\nequation}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\mbox{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}}
\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\mathsf{Span} ( #1 )}
\newcommand{\Ker}[1]{\mathsf{Ker}~ }
\newcommand{\re}[1]{\mathsf{Re} ( #1 )}
\newcommand{\Ran}{\mathsf{Ran}~ }
\newcommand{\di}[1]{\mathsf{dim}~ }
\newcommand{\codim}[1]{\mathsf{codim}~ }
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\de}[1]{\mathsf{det} ( #1 )}
\newcommand{\ba}[1]{\mathsf{ball} ( #1 )}
\newcommand{\dist}[1]{\mathsf{dist} ( #1 )}

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 4pt


\DeclareMathOperator\arctanh{arctanh}
\DeclareMathOperator\arcsinh{arcsinh}
%Information to be included in the title page:


\begin{document}


    \begin{frame}{}
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be open, connected and containing the origin. We assume that the function $\Phi:\Omega\to\C$ is analytic in $\Omega$ with $\Phi(0) = 0$, Re$\Phi'(0) > 0$.  \pause
\begin{definition}
We say that $\Omega$ is {\bf $\Phi$-like}  
 if \ $\forall \alpha \in \Omega$ the initial value problem
\begin{equation}\label{Eq1}
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{dw}{dt} = -\Phi(w)\\
      w(0) = \alpha
    \end{cases}\,.
\end{equation}
has a solution $w$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ with\\ (i)  $w(t) \in \Omega,~t\ge 0$,\\ (ii) $\lim_{t\to\infty}w(t)= 0$. 
\end{definition} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. If I add `\usepackage{beamer}`,  as well as the `document` and `frame` environments around the equation, I get the expected otuput.

Comment: @leandriis I have edited in the entire preamble and the frame in question + another one to my OP. The equation in the second frame is being labelled as (0.2). I was unable to use Beamer as a package as you did, and I am not sure what the document environment is?

Comment: Sorry, `\usepackage{beamer}` in my earlier comment was definitely a typo. I wanted to write `\documentclass{beamer}`, instead. Sorry for the confusing information.

Comment: Regarding the numbering of equations iteslf: Your code contains the line `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\mbox{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}}` which explicitly asks for a numbering scheme, that prefixes the equation number with the current section's number. Remove that line and you should get the expected otuput.

Comment: Thank you very much